# Couldnt match expected type Bool error en Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.IntSet (IntSet)
-- No editar esta parte
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- readLn
  print (sumaMenosQueMax (x :: (Int, Int, Int)))

sumaMenosQueMax :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
sumaMenosQueMax x y z = if maximo x y z > medio x y z + minimo x y z then True else False
                      
maximo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
maximo x y z |maximoDos x y > z = maximoDos x y
             |otherwise = z

maximoDos :: Int -> Int -> Int
maximoDos x y | x > y = x
              |otherwise = y

minimo :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
minimo x y z |minimoDos x y < z = minimoDos x y
             |otherwise = z

minimoDos :: Int -> Int -> Int
minimoDos x y | x < y = x
              |otherwise = y

medio :: Int-> Int-> Int-> Int
medio x y z | x > y && z > x = x
            | y > x && z > y = y
            | y > x && x > z = x
            | y > z && x > y = y
            |otherwise = z
```

Why isnt working? Couldn't match expected type Bool error en Haskell. the error is just in the line `sumaMenosQueMax x y z`

Comment: signature is wrong. x y z is not the same as (x, y, z).

Answer (score 5):

The type signature says that the function that takes a tuple of 3 `Int` and returns a `Bool` but your function accepts 3 separate `Int` values, not a tuple of 3 `Int` values.

Modify your function definition to accept a tuple like this and it will compile:

```hs
sumaMenosQueMax (x, y, z) = if maximo x y z > medio x y z + minimo x y z then True else False
```

---

The `if` expression is also redundant here, it can just be:

```hs
sumaMenosQueMax (x, y, z) = maximo x y z > medio x y z + minimo x y z
```

Comment: _Any_ `if cond then True else False` is equivalent to simply `cond`.